# XSLT checking passed param string value in a choose/when format

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'm attempting to read in parameters from a C# program, with userPrimaryInput being a selection between the letters R or T to represent different categories of results and userSecondary input being the index of the C# array that matches the xml node number. My problem is that despite putting it all within a choose/when block based on the user input for desired html output, it only ever seems to produce the first when.

My question, then, is how do I properly use the choose/when format to check a parameter that is a string (which would be the userPrimaryInput param here)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>



<xsl:param name="userPrimaryInput"/>

<xsl:param name="userSecondaryInput"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:choose>
  <!--IF Region select-->
   <xsl:when test="userPrimaryInput = R | userPrimaryInput = r "><!--Region 
select if-->
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>

     Incidents of Crime in <xsl:value-of select="/crime-in-
         canada/region[position()=$userSecondaryInput]/@name"/>, 2013
    </h1>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Crime Type</th>
        <th>Incidents</th>
        <th>Rate(incidents/100,000)</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>

          <xsl:for-each select="/crime-in-  
           canada/region[position()=$userSecondaryInput]/crime">
            <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="@incidents"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="(@incidents div (../population-millions*1000000 div 100000))"/>
        </td>
     </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:when><!--End of region select if -->
<!--IF Type select-->
  <xsl:when test="userPrimaryInput = T | userPrimaryInput = t ">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>

          Incidents of <xsl:value-of select="/crime-in-
    canada/region/crime[position()=$userSecondaryInput]/@type"/> Across All 
    Regions, 2013
        </h1>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <th>Crime Type</th>
            <th>Incidents</th>
            <th>Rate(incidents/100,000)</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>

            <xsl:for-each select="/crime-in-
 canada/region/crime[position()=$userSecondaryInput]">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@incidents"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="(@incidents div (../population-
 millions*1000000 div 100000))"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am surprised you get anything output, because I think the culprit is this line....

```
<xsl:when test="userPrimaryInput = R | userPrimaryInput = r ">
```

There are three problems here...

1. You have missed out the `$` prefix for `userPrimaryInput`, so it is looking for an element called `userPrimaryInput`, and not the parameter
2. Doing `userPrimaryInput = R` means it is looking to compare it with an element named `R`. Use `'R'` to compare it with a string literal
3. `|` is the union operator. It is not a logical "or" operator. Use "or" here!

So, the test should be like so

```
<xsl:when test="$userPrimaryInput = 'R' or $userPrimaryInput = 'r'">
```

And similarly for the line testing for `T` (or you could use `xsl:otherwise` here too)

Comment: Hahah wow, don't I feel stupid. So, I actually knew about all of those except I implemented them separately as individual fixes that didn't seem to work, rather than the three I needed to actually get it working. Thanks!